# How to prove that this function is not 1-1

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The following question was part of my analysis assignment and I couldn't solve this part out of 5parts.

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ be a function $f(x,y)=( x^2 -y^2 , 2xy) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Is  f 1-1 on $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

I let $(x^2-y^2, 2xy)=(p^2-q^2, 2pq)$  but neither I am able to prove p=x and q=y nor able to find a contradictory exam ple.

Your guidance is required!

Comment: Note that with complex $z= x+iy$ this is just $f(z) = z^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jjagmath is right. Tip: When even-power terms appear prominently like that, always try plugging the negatives. But if you aren't able to find a counterexample just by "looking at it", you can try this to be more systematic (espacially if it's more complicated).

Assume $f(x,y) = (u,v)$, and solve for $(x,y)$. Then
$$
y = \frac{v}{2x}
$$
so
$$
x^2 - \frac{v^2}{4x^2} = u
\iff x = \pm\sqrt{\frac{u+\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}{2}}
$$
so
$$
y = \pm\frac{v}{2\sqrt{\frac{u+\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}{2}}}
$$
So we clearly have two solutions for each $(u,v)$. (Actually the above assumes $v\ne 0$ for convenience).

Answer (score 2):

We have $f(x,y) = f(-x, -y)$ so it's not injective